# Using OSM data, pgRouting, and dummy data to develop an origin/destination travel matrix

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, transportation, osm2pgrouting

Further to my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2127/127) I was wondering if it is possible to add dummy node data without to do routing analysis.

### ISSUE

- I have a polygon layer that represents zonal attributes
- I created a centroid (point layer) for each polygon
- I would like to add the new points to the database with "dummy" links to the nearest highway or nearest road of a certain classification
- Route from between all the nodes to develop a trip matrix

Is this possible with OSM and pgRouting?

**NOTE** I will add more details to this question tomorrow

Comment: The bounty is still in 'a grace period' (it still can be given 24hrs after the expiry time) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create an INSERT statement that constructs a line from your centroid to your road segment.

Some useful postgis functions would be:

- st_make_line
- line_locate_point(ST_GeometryN(road.geom, 1), centroid.geom)
- st_distance(road.geom, centroid.geom)

Comment: Can you detail this a bit more?