# Shortest path between multiple points in pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting

I have used [this](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) great tutorial, and shortest part between two points works fine.
My question is: 
***How to calculate shortest path between multiple points?***

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question. It's not clear what exactly you are looking for. Best include a sketch.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19056/using-osm-data-pgrouting-and-dummy-data-to-develop-an-origin-destination-trave) that I asked before if it's any good to you

Answer (score 5):

there is a modified shortest_path which enables multiple destinations;

Take a look at https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/One_to_many-Dijkstra---To-review 
or the forked pgrouting https://github.com/HSylvio/pgrouting

Hope it works as well for you as it does for me!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple start points and a single finish point, another approach may be using Cost Path command in Raster Calculator as follows:

CostPath("Inicial_points","Costs","Direction")

Comparing paths with rivers, we can use "Inicial_points" = Headwaters, "Costs" = Digital Elevation Model and "Direction" = Flow Direction.